# Using floating curly braces to free variables early in C#

Tags: c#, optimization, coding-style, garbage-collection, curly-braces

C# variables are instantiated where the type is declared (eg `string s;`) and freed at the closing brace of the current scope:

```
// Operates with Q memory
void FantasyMethod() {
    var o = new BigObject();

    {
        var temp = new BigObject();
        Populate(temp); // Populates o1 with N megabytes of data

        o = PerformSomeOperationsOn(temp); // Returns a BigObject of size M (M is close to N)

        // Currently, M+N memory is occupied, we have Q-M-N free
    }

    // Let's tell the garbage collector to catch up
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    // Currently, M memory is occupied

    DoUsefulStuffWith(o); // This method can only work if at least Q-M-N/2 memory is free
}
```

One benefit of this is that I can free large variables before the function returns. In the above (trivial) block, I have husbanded my limited available memory by disposing a large variable as soon as it is no longer needed.

1. Is the above correct?
2. Is doing this a good idea (I am interested in arguments for and against, not personal opinion or preference)? Would extracting the naked brace block as a method use memory less efficiently? What if I don't want to make a new method for readability reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One benefit of this is that I can free large variables before the function returns.

No.  C# isn't C++, objects don't have destructors, and you are not guaranteed that an object will be reclaimed the moment it leaves its declaring scope and no valid references to it exist.

If you need that level of predictability then you shouldn't be using a managed language, period.  Techniques do exist which can help to alleviate memory pressure in C#, but they are not often needed and you will never get the level of control that a language like C or C++ will give you.

Per your edit:

[GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) will *attempt* to run a GC pass, it doesn't guarantee it.  [GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers.aspx) blocks until all objects which have been marked for finalization have run their finalizers.

> If an object implements a finalizer and has not disabled finalization by calling SuppressFinalize, the object is placed in a list of objects that are marked as ready for finalization. The garbage collector calls the Finalize methods for the objects in this list and removes the entries from the list. This method blocks until all finalizers have run to completion.

Comment: I changed the question to make it less ambiguous whether garbage collection is performed. Hopefully the GC calls are correct.

Comment: +0: Not exactly correct - in this particular sample there is no change in GC eligibility as `temp` is eligible for GC immediately after last usage, which in the sample coincides with end of inner block, but would be at the same place without inner block too. (Note this comment about release/optimized JIT behavior, in debug mode scope is longer)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Good point, I removed it.  I'm not knowledgeable enough about the GC to make a claim like that.  Thanks.

Comment: So with my edit, is it correct that my use of braces and a GC call has allowed to free up memory for the memory intensive `DoUsefulStuffWith` method? If I had not used curly braces, would GC not collect `temp`?

Comment: @Superbest: In this case, limiting the scope is not helpful.  As Alexei pointed out "`temp` is eligible for GC immediately after last usage".  You really need to profile your app, memory usage in a managed language is just not as deterministic as you would seem to want.

Comment: I agree that optimization should always be done after profiling, but in this case I don't actually have a memory problem. I was just curious in how this situation is handled in C# - I didn't know the GC already takes into account variable usage. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Superbest: I actually meant profiling *after* adding the change (I assumed you did actually have a memory issue).  I have had to use those two `GC` calls before, and it helped, though in my case I was creating a ton of small objects quickly and they weren't being cleaned up as fast as I needed.

Comment: @Superbest: Also, do you know where the memory problem lies, i.e., is this causing LOH fragmentation?

Answer (score 2):

Your presumptions aren't entirely correct. Unlike C++ the objects aren't immediately destroyed (or if we want to be pedantic, have the destructor called) when they are out of scope. All that can be guaranteed is that if a GC sweep occurs while there are absolutely no references pointing to the objects instantiated within the closed scope then the object would be *collected*.

And even if you don't enclose the use of an object within an explicit scope the compiler already has enough information to 'know' that the object isn't being used/referenced anyway so you won't be doing it any favours.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect, assuming `BigObject` is not a value type. If `BigObject` is a class then it will always exist on the managed heap and will not be deterministically disposed of after it falls out of scope. The GC runs in another thread and you cannot predict when it will do a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard that placing a variable inside of a block would free the variable. Also what do you mean by freeing?  Memory is managed by the garbage collector and it will determine when to free memory.

If the "variable" is holding a resource then it should implement IDisposable; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and your could should be:

```
using (var b = new DisposableObject())
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: It cannot be assumed that BigObject implements IDisposable in my case.

Comment: My comment states "should implement IDisposable" and then ...  Also, if it doesn't implement the interface, then the compiler will complain.